# How to connect cnosdb through odbc？

Tags: cnosdb

When I use odbc to connect to cnosdb according to the document https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/reference/connector/arrow_flight_sql.html#different-client-usage, when I execute `isql -v CNOSDB`, it does not get expected response, but hang